# Start activity from widget

Tags: android, android-intent, widget

So I have seen many solutions on how to launch an activity from an android widget, now my question is, do I need to declare something in the manifest for the activity to be launched? I have an activity with its layout and I have the widget provider with the pending intent, which is triggered when I click on a button, but it wont take me to the activity. here is my code

```
final int N = appWidgetIds.length;

    // Perform this loop procedure for each App Widget that belongs to this provider
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];

        // Create an Intent to launch ExampleActivity
        Intent intent = new Intent(context, WidgetActivity.class);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);

        // Get the layout for the App Widget and attach an on-click listener
        // to the button
        RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);
        views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.button1, pendingIntent);

        // Tell the AppWidgetManager to perform an update on the current app widget
        appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
```

same code from developer.android but with my button id and my activity name...

Answer (score 0):

You need to define your activity in the manifest. e.g.,

```
<activity android:name="org.achartengine.GraphicalActivity" />
```

Do you see any errors in logcat?

There are many working examples on the web, you can also check my open source app which has a widget and activity:

https://code.google.com/p/currentwidget/

Try to add:

```
intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
```

after you create your intent.

Comment: I do not get any errors on logcat, also I have the activity on the manifest but it does not have any intents associated with it is that somthing I may have missed?

Comment: Try intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); after you create your intent.

Comment: nothing happens, i am desperate I assigned the pending intent to a button I have on the layout and y just sits there I click it and nothing....